# F# Functions vs. Values

Tags: f#

This is a pretty simple question, and I just wanted to check that what I'm doing and how I'm interpreting the F# makes sense. If I have the statement

```
let printRandom = 
  x = MyApplication.getRandom()
  printfn "%d" x
  x
```

Instead of creating `printRandom` as a function, F# runs it once and then assigns it a value. So, now, when I call printRandom, instead of getting a new random value and printing it, I simply get whatever was returned the first time. I can get around this my defining it as such:

```
let printRandom() = 
  x = MyApplication.getRandom()
  printfn "%d" x
  x
```

Is this the proper way to draw this distinction between parameter-less functions and values? This seems less than ideal to me. Does it have consequences in currying, composition, etc?

Comment: Note that you almost certainly want to add a `let` in front of the first occurrence of `x` - otherwise you are performing a comparison and then throwing away the result.

Comment: Awesome question, was having the *exact* same problem.  Unfortunately I found this after I discovered the solution.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The right way to look at this is that F# has no such thing as parameter-less functions. All functions have to take a parameter, but sometimes you don't care what it is, so you use `()` (the singleton value of type unit). You could also make a function like this:

```
let printRandom unused = 
  x = MyApplication.getRandom()
  printfn "%d" x
  x
```

or this:

```
let printRandom _ = 
  x = MyApplication.getRandom()
  printfn "%d" x
  x
```

But `()` is the default way to express that you don't use the parameter. It expresses that fact to the caller, because the type is `unit -> int` not `'a -> int`; as well as to the reader, because the call site is `printRandom ()` not `printRandom "unused"`.

Currying and composition do in fact rely on the fact that all functions take one parameter and return one value.

The most common way to write calls with unit, by the way, is with a space, especially in the non .NET relatives of F# like Caml, SML and Haskell. That's because `()` is a singleton value, not a syntactic thing like it is in C#.

Answer (score 9):

Your analysis is correct.

The first instance defines a value and not a function.  I admit this caught me a few times when I started with F# as well.  Coming from C# it seems very natural that an assignment expression which contains multiple statements must be a lambda and hence delay evaluated.

This is just not the case in F#.  Statements can be almost arbitrarily nested (and it rocks for having locally scoped functions and values).  Once you get comfortable with this you start to see it as an advantage as you can create functions and continuations which are inaccessible to the rest of the function.

The second approach is the standard way for creating a function which logically takes no arguments.  I don't know the precise terminology the F# team would use for this declaration though (perhaps a function taking a single argument of type `unit`).  So I can't really comment on how it would affect currying.

Comment: Currying doesn't really apply here since the function only has one parameter, of type `unit`. Partial application doesn't make sense: you either fully apply the function (passing `()`), or you don't call it at all.

Answer (score 7):

> Is this the proper way to draw this
>   distinction between parameter-less
>   functions and values? This seems less
>   than ideal to me. Does it have
>   consequences in currying, composition,
>   etc?

Yes, what you describe is correct.

For what its worth, it has a very interesting consequence able to partially evaluate functions on declaration. Compare these two functions:

```
// val contains  : string -> bool
let contains =
    let people = set ["Juliet"; "Joe"; "Bob"; "Jack"]
    fun person -> people.Contains(person)

// val contains2 : string -> bool
let contains2 person =
    let people = set ["Juliet"; "Joe"; "Bob"; "Jack"]
    people.Contains(person)
```

Both functions produce identical results, `contains` creates its people set on declaration and reuses it, whereas `contains2` creates its people set everytime you call the function. End result: `contains` is slightly faster. So knowing the distinction here can help you write faster code.

Answer (score 4):

Assignment bodies looking like function bodies have cought a few programmers unaware. You can make things even more interesting by having the assignment return a function:

```
let foo =
    printfn "This runs at startup"
    (fun () -> printfn "This runs every time you call foo ()")
```

I just wrote a blog post about it at http://blog.wezeku.com/2010/08/23/values-functions-and-a-bit-of-both/.