# When to use parentheses on method declaration?

Tags: f#

If I declare a method with no parameters and then call it (in F#-interactive), then I get the expected behaviour: "test" is displayed on screen.

```
let somefn() = 
    printfn "test"
> 
val somefn : unit -> unit

> somefn();;
test
val it : unit = ()
```

However, If I declare the method without parentheses, then I get some different behavior:

```
let somefn = 
    printfn "test"
> 
test
val somefn : unit = ()

> somefn;;
val it : unit = ()

> somefn();;

  somefn();;
  ^^^^^^

C:\...\Local\Temp\stdin(4,1): error FS0003: This value is not a function and cannot be applied.
```

So what I don't understand:

1. Why is method declaration without parameters so different than with parameters?
2. When I declare without parentheses, I got the message: **val somefn : unit = ()**. What does it mean unit = ()? What exactly did I declared now? What sort of entity is **somefn** now?
3. It is obviously that now there's an entity called **somefn**, which points to some executable code. How can I execute that code? can I declare **somefn** as member of a struct or something and execute it from there?

Comment: without parameters it isn't a function, just a value.

Comment: Here is a link with some more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554750/f-functions-vs-values

Comment: Note that there are no methods here, just functions, which are different.

Comment: The first function (not method) you displayed, namely somefn(), is not a function without parameters. It has a parameter of type unit, namely (), which is the only instance of the type unit.

Answer (score 7):

The comments above answer this question but I'll add some detail.

When you define a function, each parameter is actually a pattern match with only one case. For example you could write:

```
let somefn 0 = 1
```

The type of this function is `int -> int`. The first parameter is inferred to be an `int`, but this generates a warning because there are other ints that are not being matched on. `somefn 0` returns `1`, but `somefn 1` throws an exception `"The match cases were incomplete"`.

The type `unit` has only one value: `()`. It's effectively as a "nothing" value for the input or an output of a function. It has a pattern match that looks exactly like the value (just like `[]` for an empty list), which is why you can add a unit parameter to any function using `()`. These functions are all exactly the same:

```
let somefn () = ()
let somefn (x:unit) = ()
let somefn (_:unit) = ()
```

When you write a function that doesn't take any parameters, you just add a single `unit` parameter so that it's a function and not a value, and therefore you delay its execution. Just to drive the point home, you could even add more than one `unit` parameter, although you would never need to do this:

```
let somefn () () = ()
// unit -> unit -> unit
```