# Which Async implementation is best practice

Tags: f#

I just can't seem to find a straight enough answer to this.  I can't understand why someone would choose "Get" over "Get2".

- In "Get", async will bleed all over my code like C#.  In C#, this is for good reasons.  Is this true for f# as well?  async doesn't seem compose as well, functionally.  Just like C#.
- In "Get2", I've returned a value without a wrapper.  The caller does not have to "await" anything.  In C#, this is impossible without calling "GetAwaiter().GetResult()".

Unless there are technical reasons not to, I would always choose "Get2".  That way my code can be async at the io edges of the app rather than everywhere.  Can someone please help me understand why you would choose one over the other.  Or the circumstances for both?  I understand the threading and execution model of async/await in C#, but not how to ensure I'm doing the same thing in f#.

```
member this.Get (url : string) : Async<'a> = async {
    use client = new HttpClient()
    let! response = client.GetAsync(url) |> Async.AwaitTask 

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() |> ignore

    let! content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask

    return this.serializer.FromJson<'a>(content)
    }

member this.Get2 (url : string) : 'a = 
    use client = new HttpClient()
    let response = client.GetAsync(url) |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() |> ignore

    let content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously

    this.serializer.FromJson<'a>(content);
```

Comment: Where did you get the impression that async doesn't compose?

Comment: If you think async doesn't compose, you have not yet read and understood the https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/elevated-world/ series of articles. Depending on how much reading you've done about functional concepts like `bind` and `lift`, you may or may not be able to grasp that series immediately, or it might take several attempts to read it before you "get it". (I know for me, it took me 3 or 4 attempts before I finally understood the concepts being presented). If you don't get it at first, don't worry: just bookmark that series and come back to it later.

Comment: If you follow clean | ports and adapters | hexagonal | onion architecture, async will only be an issue for at most two layers. In particular, no domain code needs to be concerned about async, it can remain at the edges of your system.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin from my lack of skills, i'm sure.  but i do read and try a lot.  i am very familiar with the fsharpfor... site.  i've been going there for a while and i have his new book.  self-teaching has it's limitations.  i guess i'm referring mostly to the use of "let!" to reduce explicit "Async..." functions. and how "Async<'a>" bleeds up, as in C#.  I can deal with that reality.  Sometimes you just have to put the question out there and make sure.  like i said, i C# you can't "naturally" do "Get2".  I just thought there might be something I didn't understand.

Comment: @CaringDev i can probably draw 10 different diagrams that I've seen of the P&A from memory.  I find articles about it inspiring and implementation details about it lacking.  I believe I try to do this.  I'm a backend service writer with async on both sides of my code.  I do end up with some domain functionality, in the center, as pure functions.  Just not as much as I would like, I guess?  I just never know if it can be done better.  If you know any particularly good things to read, I'd appreciate it.  I read Mark Seemann's blog a lot.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you're writing a program that can afford to block, such as a console application, then by all means, block. `Get2` is fine if you can afford to block.

But the truth is, most modern programs cannot afford to block. For example, in a rich GUI app, you can't afford to hold up the UI thread while you're doing your long-running thing: the UI will freeze and the user will be displeased. At the same time, you also cannot afford to just do everything in background, because eventually you need to push the results back into the UI, and that can only be done on the UI thread. So your only choice is to slice your logic into a chain of background calls with callbacks that ends back on the UI thread. Async computations (as well as C# `async`/`await`) do that for you transparently.

For another example, a web server cannot really afford to keep a live thread for every active request: that would severely limit the server's throughput. Instead, the server needs to issue long-running requests to the operating system with on-completion callbacks, which would form a chain ultimately ending with a response to the client.

This last point, perhaps, needs special clarification, because, as I have discovered, the difference between keeping an active background thread and issuing OS requests is not immediately clear to everybody. The way most OS calls are built (deep at the lowest level) is along this pattern: "*Dear Operating System, please go ask the network card to receive some packets on this socket, and wake me up when that's done*" (I'm somewhat simplifying here). This operation is represented in .NET API as `HttpClient.GetAsync`. The important point about this operation is that, while it is in progress, *there is no thread that is waiting for its completion*. Your application has kicked the can over to the OS side, and can happily go spend its precious threads on something different - like accepting more connections from clients or whatever.

Now, if you explicitly block on this operation with `Async.RunSynchronously`, that means you've just condemned your current thread to sit there and wait for the operation to complete. This thread cannot be used for anything else now until the operation is done. If you do this in every single instance, your server is now spending a thread per active connection. This is a big no-no. Threads are not cheap. And there is a limit on them. You've basically built yourself a *toy* server.

The bottom line is, C# `async`/`await` and F# `async` weren't invented just to satisfy the language designers' itch: they were sorely needed. If you're building serious software, at a certain point you are bound to discover that you can't just block everywhere, and your code turns into a mess of callbacks. And that's exactly the state most code was in just a few years ago.

---

I have not answered the claim that "async doesn't seem to compose well", because that claim is unsubstantiated. If you were to clarify which specific difficulties you see with composing async computations, I would be happy to amend my answer.

---

### Edit: in response to comments

F# `async` and C# `Task` are *not* exactly analogous. There is a subtle difference: F# `async` is what we call "cold", while C# `Task` is what we call "hot" (see e.g. [cold vs. hot observables](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339)). In plain terms, the difference is that a `Task` is "already running", while an `async` is only getting ready to run.

If you have a `Task` object in your hand, it means that whatever computation that object represents is already "in flight", already started, already running, and there is nothing you can do about that. You can wait for its completion, and you can obtain its result, but you can't prevent it from running, or restart it, or anything else like that.

F# `async` computation, on the other hand, is a computation that is "ready to go", but is not going yet. You can start it with `Async.Start` or `Async.RunSynchronously`, or whatever, but it's not doing anything until you do. One important corollary of this is that you can start it *multiple times*, and those would be separate, different, completely independent executions.

For example, consider this F# code:

```
let delay = async { 
    do! Task.Delay(500) |> Async.AwaitTask 
    return () 
}

let f = async {
    do! delay
    do! delay
    do! delay
}
```

and this (not quite) equivalent C# code:

```
var delay = Task.Delay(500);

var f = new Func<Task>( async () => {
    await delay;
    await delay;
    await delay;
});

f().Wait();
```

The F# version would take exactly 1500ms, while the C# version - exactly 500ms. This is because in C# `delay` is a single computation that runs for 500ms and stops, and that's it; but in F# `delay` is not running until it's used in a `do!`, and even then, each `do!` starts a new instance of `delay`.

One way to distill all of the above would be this: F# `async` is equivalent not to C# `Task`, but rather to `Func<Task>` - that is, it's not a computation itself, but a way to start a new computation.

### Now, having that background, let's look at your individual small questions:

> So, for the record, the async {} expression is specifically the functional equivalent to async/await in C# correct?

Kind of, but not exactly. See the explanation above.

> And coupling that with "AwaitTask" calls (as above) is.... normal?

Kind of, but not exactly. As a way to consume C#-centric .NET APIs - yes, it's normal to use `AwaitTask`. But if you're writing your program entirely in F# and using only F# libraries, then tasks shouldn't really enter the picture at all.

> it's async & let! that are the direct equivalents to async/await. Am i right?

Again, kind of, but not exactly. `let!` and `do!` are indeed direct equivalents of `await`, but F# `async` is not exactly the same as C# `async` - see explanation above. There is also `return!`, which does not have a direct equivalent in C# syntax.

> And RunSync... is for some specific context where blocking is acceptable.

Yes. Usually, `RunSynchronously` is used at a boundary. It's used to "convert" an asynchronous computation into a synchronous one. It is equivalent to `Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.

> If I want to expose that function to C# it would have to be returned back into a Task. Is "StartAsTask" the way to do that?

Again: kind of, but not exactly. Keep in mind that a `Task` is an "already running" computation, so you have to be careful about how exactly you turn your `async` into a `Task`. Consider this example:

```
let f = async { ... whatever ... } |> Async.StartAsTask

let g () = async { ... whatever ... } |> Async.StartAsTask
```

Here, the body of `f` will be executed at initialization time, and the task will start running immediately when your program starts running, and every time somebody takes the value of `f`, it will be always the same task. Probably not what you intuitively expect.

On the other hand, `g` will create a new task every time it is called. Why? Because it has an unit argument `()`, and so its body doesn't execute until somebody calls it with that argument. And every time it will be a new body execution, a new call to `Async.StartAsTask`, and therefore, a new `Task`. If you're still confused about what the empty parentheses `()` are doing exactly, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554750/f-functions-vs-values).

> does [StartAsTask] explicitly start a new thread immediately?

Yes, it does. But guess what? That's actually exactly what C# does anyway! If you have a method `public async void f() { ... }`, every time you *call* it like `f()`, that call does, in fact, start a new thread immediately. Well, to be more precise, it starts a new *computtion* immediately - that may not always result in a new thread. `Async.StartAsTask` does exactly the same thing.

> is that a compromise that must be made for that kind of interop?

Yes, this is an approach that must be taken for that kind of interop, but I don't see why it's a "compromise".

Comment: Unsubstantiated "composability" claims aside, this is really what I need to know.  I'm familiar with how async/await works.  C# makes it awkward to do it wrong.  F# kind of made it easy, kinda?  "RunSynchronously" can be placed in similar proximity as "await".  I thought it might function the same.  I'll admit, "RunSynchronously" does sound ominous and I suspected async expressions were going to be the answer.  I just couldn't find a direct enough answer for my satisfaction.  I'm a C# service dev and I'm used to async/await just being everywhere.  thanks for the help!

Comment: So, for the record, the async {} expression is specifically the functional equivalent to async/await in C# correct?  And coupling that with "AwaitTask" calls (as above) is.... normal?  i'm just going to get all of my ignorance out on the table here and get it over with :)

Comment: it's async & let! that are the direct equivalents to async/await.  Am i right?  And AwaitTask is just a way to transform a Task to an Async?  And RunSync...  is for some specific context where blocking is acceptable.  If I want to expose that function to C# it would have to be returned back into a Task.  Is "StartAsTask" the way to do that?  or does that explicitly start a new thread immediately?  is that a compromise that must be made for that kind of interop?

Comment: Ok, I have amended the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer.  I means a lot to me to get past such a small thing that I just couldn't quite get the low-down on.

Comment: @TBone I‘d argue exactly the opposite way: C# makes it awkward to do the right thing... there’s (much) more to async than discussed here. Especially when e.g. SynchronizationContext and exception handling come into play, F# is superior.

Comment: @CaringDev interesting.  i guess i only meant that C# has two keywords and exceptions are aggregated.  it's probably just what i'm familiar with, but it seems straight forward.  I'll have to read further into what you're talking about hear.  my largest problem was that i didn't want to block threads and F# has... more than two keywords :)  there doesn't seem to be anywhere in my area to do f# for a living, so i'm always trying to learn this on the side and get other people interested as well.  examples on the internet are not always trustworthy i find.  i'll have to find a good book, i think.

Answer (score 2):

`async` in F# and `async/await` in C# are in some sense an implementation of `coroutine` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine) a term coined in 1958 by Melvin Conway.

Normal functions and C# and F# are `subroutines`. The thing is:

```
Subroutines are special cases of ... coroutines.
— Donald Knuth
```

What this is means is that we `invoke`a  `subroutine`, it then runs to completion when it `return` (potentially an exception).

`coroutine` can in addition `yield` and `resume`.

When a `subroutine` reads IO it needs to block while waiting for the IO. A `coroutine` can however `yield` to let another `coroutine` execute and when IO signals as ready the `coroutine` then `resume`. The benefit for us is that a single thread can then be shared to serve many `coroutine` where each `subroutine` must be served by a single thread.

`coroutines` can be beneficial in the `C10k problem`  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem) as we don't need a thread per connection. Instead we have a limited pool of threads servicing 10,000 `coroutine` that do `yield` and `resume` for IO.

One of the problems with `async/await` in C# is what happens when a `subroutine` (normal functions) starts a `coroutine` (`async` function)? The `coroutine` might wish to `yield` but that is an operation that normal functions in .NET don't support. This happens when we call `.Value` on the `async` task.

```
var task = MyAsyncFunction();
var result = task.Value; // Hmm but what if the MyAsyncFunction needs to yield.
```

So at `.Value` "interesting" things might happen. We might have a dead-lock or we might not. Regardless we lost the benefit of `coroutines` in that our thread is now blocking on `.Value`.

This is one of the reasons that some argue that one should use `async` all the way and never rely on `.Value` or `.Wait()`.

`async` functions can call `async` functions and normal functions. Normal functions can't call or at least block on `async` functions.

So if we look at `Get` and `Get2` in the question above I then wonder what is the benefit of `Get2` over `Get3`:

```
member this.Get3 (url : string) : 'a = 
    use client = new HttpClient()
    let response = client.Get(url) 

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() |> ignore

    let content = response.Content.ReadAsString()

    this.serializer.FromJson<'a>(content);
```

It seems to me that `Get2` is more complicated then use using normal functions all the way and doesn't give any benefits.

`Get1` provides the benefit that it's a `coroutine` that share the thread with other `coroutine`.

PS. IMHO it is a mistake to include an operation that blocks on a `coroutine` in the API such as `.Value`, `.Wait` or `RunSynchronously`. This operation removes the benefit of why we like to `async` the first place.