# How can I repeat functions in F# after a function has been called inside it?

Tags: function, recursion, f#

I have a game where you can do certain actions, then after the action is done I have a list of actions you can do again but after it's been completed once the program ends, I thought because it's a recursive function it will keep going.

This is not part of my game but just a demonstration, this program asks for a string once then finishes. Shouldn't it keep asking for a string, and how can I make it do that? I also tried calling back to the recursive function inside the f1 function but of course f1 does not know it exists.

```
open System

let f1 x =
    printfn "Hello, %s" x

let rec f2 =
    let x = Console.ReadLine()
    f1 x

Console.Read() |> ignore
```

Comment: In your code `f2` is not a function, it is value.

Comment: @PetSerAl How do I make it a function? I don't see the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you define `f2` as a value, not as a function. This has been discussed on StackOverflow before and there is a [good question and answer that covers this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554750/f-functions-vs-values)

The other problem is that you probably want to call `f2` from `f1` (to continue looping) as well as call `f1` from `f2`. To do this, you can define the functions as mutually recursive using `let rec .. and` syntax:

```
let rec f1 x =
    printfn "Hello, %s" x
    f2 ()

and f2 () =
    let x = Console.ReadLine()
    f1 x
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation but the code you provided doesn't ask for the string repeatedly. Edit: It does, I just had to call it after. :P