# Why are both functions called when the condition is not met?

Tags: f#

I have written this F# console application (that should call the `run` method only if the condition is met - if the directory exists):

```
open System

let dump (x: string) =
    Console.WriteLine(x)

let validateDirectory directory funToCallWhenOk =
    match (System.IO.Directory.Exists directory) with 
    | true -> funToCallWhenOk
    | false -> dump (sprintf "Problem with '%s'" directory)
    //if System.IO.Directory.Exists directory then
    //    funToCallWhenOk
    //else
    //    dump (sprintf "Problem with '%s'" directory)

let Watch directory =
    let run = 
        dump (sprintf "Now watching '%s'" directory)
        dump "Press 'q' to quit"

    validateDirectory directory run


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =

    Watch @"c:\temp\resize1"

    0
```

The currently specified directory does not exist, but the `run` function is called anyway, regardles if using `match .. when` or `if then else`. The console output:

[image]

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't defined `run` as a function but as a `unit` value. You must define it as a function and call the function in `validateDirectory`:

```
let validateDirectory directory funToCallWhenOk =
    match (System.IO.Directory.Exists directory) with 
    | true -> funToCallWhenOk()
    | false -> dump (sprintf "Problem with '%s'" directory)
    //if System.IO.Directory.Exists directory then
    //    funToCallWhenOk
    //else
    //    dump (sprintf "Problem with '%s'" directory)

let Watch directory =
    let run() = 
        dump (sprintf "Now watching '%s'" directory)
        dump "Press 'q' to quit"

    validateDirectory directory run
```

Comment: Ah, thanks - now it works correct! I thought that there is no difference and the `unit` is something like `void`, but I need to take a deeper look at this topic.

Comment: @keenthinker What you had before (`let run = dump ...`) just meant: let `run` be whatever is the result of evaluating `dump ...`. So it first had to evaluate `dump ...` and then assign the result of that to `run`, namely `unit` (which is indeed like `void`).

Comment: A good explanation of the difference can be found in this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554750/f-functions-vs-values. run is a function, but the absense of the not needed parameter `()` = `unit` changes the behaviour.